# How to keep a TXT file synced with a List<string>

Tags: c#, io

So, I'm making a text based game in C#, and I am creating a profile feature. It already creates a new TXT file when it is executed for the first time and stores it in the appdata folder. Now, here is what is in that TXT file;

```
NAME=[$]
REP=[0]
```

The 'NAME' operator is for a personal alias, and is what I am working on at the moment. What I need it to do, is upon entering a command;

```
alias Example
```

It will modify a List which contains exactly that, in short, synced with the TXT file. I have tried many, many different ways, including;

```
case "alias":
    string joined = string.Join(",", profileList.ToArray());
    string[] joineone = joined.Split(',');

    profileList.Clear();
    foreach (string var in joineone)
    {
        if (var.StartsWith("NAME"))
        {
            var.Replace(getStringBetween(var, "[", "]"), preCut[1]);
        }
        profileList.Add(var);
    }
    Invoke(new _rewriteProfile(rewriteProfile));
    break;
```

and a much shorter version;

```
profileList[0].Replace(getStringBetween(profileList[0],"=[", "]"), preCut[1]);
```

Where `profileList` is the synced one with the TXT file and `getStringBetween` gets a string between two characters. It is also hooked up to a replace, to replace it with the first "cut", which in this case is 'Example'. The thing is, it never changes. The text just does not change in the list. I have NO IDEA why. I am using .NET 2.0 by the way.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly "never changes"? The file on the disk doesn't change its content, or something else?

Comment: NAME=[$] must never change, only the '$' (text) inside of it.
Same with the REP=[0], but the 0 can go up. Problem is, it doesn't. I've tried everything I can think of!, thanks for your reply!

Comment: You didn't say which version of c# you are using. But if you are using 4.0 or up, you can use the `ObservableCollection<T>` class to create a collection, which fires event when it is changed.

Comment: I am using .NET 2.0 by the way.
At the bottom of the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var = var.Replace(getStringBetween(var, "[", "]"), preCut[1]);

Answer (score 0):

Check if the txt file is read only...... or maybe your method (getStringBetween) does not return any thing.

Comment: I have verified both! I haven't even been writing it to the text file for testing, I've been outputting it to the console! And it reads, the output from the getStringBetween is always "$", but the end result is always NAME=[$]

Comment: what is the value of precut[1]??

Comment: preCut is the chosen alias, for example alias Example,
preCut will be 'Example'